# Within how many days do I have to choose a proposed alternate option due to schedule change caused by WizzAir?

Tags: wizz-air

I've got a message from WizzAir that my flight schedule was altered. I've been given three options: a) 120% refund, b) rebook, c) default rebook.

How many days since the message reception do I have to choose between these options?

I couldn't find any relevant information on the WizzAir help.

Comment: The longer you wait, the fewer re-booking options will likely be available. Do you have any particular reason to delay making a choice?

Comment: the ticket is for 5 seats, so I need to sync with 5 people to make the final call hence the delay

Answer (score 3):

Got an answer from WizzAir - it is 24h prior to the departure.